# Using a stored procedure to select the top (x) rows and sorting each row into a different parameter

Tags: sql, plc

I am fairly limited in my SQL knowledge.

I have a table that records anytime a change is made to a part count of a bin. I am trying to write a stored procedure where I can select the top (x) records pertaining to a certain bin and then funnel the information for each individual record to a set of different parameters.  For instance I would like all the columns for the very first record to go into parameter set 1, the next record to go into parameter set 2, etc...

My first attempt at the stored procedure is below, it does populate the parameters with the very top record information, but I'm not sure what needs to change to bring each subsequent record. Also, if it makes a difference to anyone, I am sending this information to an Allen-Bradley PLC using Transaction Manager.  Thank you in advance.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GBT_SPROC]
    
    @GBT_COLUMN_A VARCHAR(255),
    @GBT_COLUMN_B_1 INT OUT,
    @GBT_COLUMN_C_1 VARCHAR(255) OUT,
    @GBT_COLUMN_D_1 VARCHAR(255) OUT,
    @GBT_COLUMN_E_1 VARCHAR(255) OUT,
    @GBT_COLUMN_B_2 INT OUT,
    @GBT_COLUMN_C_2 VARCHAR(255) OUT,
    @GBT_COLUMN_D_2 VARCHAR(255) OUT,
    @GBT_COLUMN_E_2 VARCHAR(255) OUT,
    @GBT_COLUMN_B_3 INT OUT,
    @GBT_COLUMN_C_3 VARCHAR(255) OUT,
    @GBT_COLUMN_D_3 VARCHAR(255) OUT,
    @GBT_COLUMN_E_3 VARCHAR(255) OUT
    
    
AS
BEGIn
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select TOP (3)
    @GBT_COLUMN_B_1 = COLUMN_B,
    @GBT_COLUMN_C_1 = COLUMN_C,
    @GBT_COLUMN_D_1 = COLUMN_D,
    @GBT_COLUMN_E_1 = COLUMN_E,
    @GBT_COLUMN_B_2 = COLUMN_B,
    @GBT_COLUMN_C_2 = COLUMN_C,
    @GBT_COLUMN_D_2 = COLUMN_D,
    @GBT_COLUMN_E_2 = COLUMN_E,
    @GBT_COLUMN_B_3 = COLUMN_B,
    @GBT_COLUMN_C_3 = COLUMN_C,
    @GBT_COLUMN_D_3 = COLUMN_D,
    @GBT_COLUMN_E_3 = COLUMN_E
    
    FROM Automation_Stock

    WHERE @GBT_COLUMN_A = COLUMN_A
    ORDER BY Date_and_Time desc
    
    
    
END
```

Comment: Are your parameters and columns really named as depicted? Why are you trying to assign the same 4 column values to 12 parameters? Ah - how do you think SQL Server knows your parameter names should align somehow with rows?

Comment: Those are not the specific names, I changed them to hopefully make the intent a little clearer.  As mentioned, this was a first attempt based on my limited, basic knowledge to begin with.  Aligning the parameter names with rows is what I'm trying to accomplish.  I want to choose the top rows sorting by "Column A," enter the "B, C, D, E" information from the first row found to the parameters ending in "_1," the "B, C, D, E" information from the 2nd row found into the parameters ending in "_2," etc. I expect the general structure and/or data types will have to change, hence asking for help.